# Can't install Dual Boot from USB live - crash and nouvea problem

Tags: installation, 13.04, dual-boot, windows-8, nouveau

I just got a new laptop with Windows 8 pre-installed and I'm trying to make a dual boot with Ubuntu on my other hard drive but I can't make the Live USB work.

I followed all the procedure for disabling the Security Boot and the UEFI setting but still doesn't work.

It seems to start the installing procedure but I never get to choose anything: after a few seconds the screen turns black with an error message;

```
[18.707838] divide error: 0000 [#1] SMP
```

It goes on for several lines quoting some `nouveau` problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: 64 bit live media since 12.04.2 should boot with secure boot enabled and in UEFI mode.  Did you try that first?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here on a XMG P303 with NVIDIA GTX 765M. KUbuntu 13.04 does run well. KUbuntu 13.10 does not boot (nor from Live USB nor after upgrading to 13.10).

A daily snapshot of KUbuntu 14.04 does boot (though no setup yet)!

Answer (score 0):

XMG C703 here.
I was able to boot Ubuntu 13.10 using "nomodeset" setting (F6 menu)